# Rubble Soil - can i re-use when turfing

Tags: lawn-repair, topsoil

I have a lawn which was previously levelled. The previous owner filled it with rubble.

I'm planning on getting the rubble completely removed, levelled and re-turfed. My question is can I improve the existing soil below the rubble by using some pre-turf fertiliser or do I need to lay (new) topsoil before re-turfing?

My plan is:

1. remove rubble
2. rotivate soil below rubble (water it too perhaps?)
3. level lawn (add topsoil where require to level)
4. add pre-turf fertiliser
5. Re-turf

Have I missed anything?

I am based in the Northern part of UK, West Yorkshire.

Thanks

Comment: How deep is the rubble? Are you sure there's actually soil under it? If you're not sure, I'd suggest digging a small test hole, possibly several in different spots.